# bootstrap slider not working in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap slider, It works fine for me if I placed it outside my container, but if i placed inside a container it did not work, Please help me out, here is my with container code:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"
    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

    </header>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
 <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
     $('.#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    })

</script>
```

but if i remove container , row, col-md-12 divs it became fine. whats the problem in my code??

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code (maybe just made when copying to SO).

you are missing a `>` on line 3

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

also in your script you have: `$('.#myCarousel').carousel({`

remove the dot as its an id you are looking for - this should be `$('#myCarousel').carousel({`

Lastly, change your divs to `<img>` tags

e.g `<img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One" alt="">`

Heres a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/cw9s99o9/1/

Answer (score 0):

syntax is wrong 
we cannot use id or class selector together (.#)

correct code is

```
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
})
```

and at line no three you did not close div end (>)
write like

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```